# Windows CE 6 / SSL Cipher Suites?

Tags: apache, ssl, encryption, windows-ce

I'm looking for a list of available cipher suites that are supported by Windows CE 6.0.

With the current SSL configuration (ssllabs.com "A rating"), old WinCE 6.0 clients are not able to talk via an encrypted connection / HTTPS to the webserver.

So, I'm wondering what outdated/insecure/weak algorithmn (RC4?) and/or protocol (SSLv3?) I need to enabled again for WinCE 6.0.

Does WinCE 6.0 support AES over TLS 1.0 ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you been able to find anything?  I am looking for the same thing right now.

Answer (score 1):

SSL Labs shows User Agent Capabilities Here:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=IE&version=6&platform=XP&key=100

I was looking for same thing because we are currently using a kiosk device with an integrated barcode scanner (like you would see in a store to check the price of something). One of our hosting environments just disabled 3DES SSL encryption, and now our kiosks can't connect. We're exploring solutions now.